# Removing frames in the 'Python' environment

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, frame

I use the `Python` environment from package `pythonhighlight` for highlighting code syntax. However, the code is always framed. Is there a possibility to switch off the frame around the code?

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
%some packages are loaded
\usepackage{pythonhighlight} %package to highlight the Python syntax

\begin{document}

\section{Python code}
\begin{python}
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit import execute, Aer, IBMQ
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

After compilation, the page look like this:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the frame around the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Always show some code so that people can see what you tried and what can be modifed. It's called a Minimal Working Example (it has to be compilable).

Comment: @Miyase: Thank you for the feedback. I improved my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `pythonhilight` seems to be a very thin (and quite useless) wrapper around `listings`. It doesn't even have a documentation. So I suggest that you use `listings` directly.

The following example includes some configuration that you can change to suit your needs:

- The `\lstset` command includes the Python syntax highlighting rules that I've been using.
- In the arguments of the `lstlisting` environment, remove the `numbers` option to remove line numbers on the left.
- Remove the `frame` option to remove the frame (this is what you asked for).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[procnames]{listings}

% Custom highlight rules for Python
\definecolor{keywords}{RGB}{255,0,90}
\definecolor{comments}{RGB}{0,0,113}
\definecolor{red}{RGB}{160,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,150,0}
\lstset{language=Python, 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
    keywordstyle=\color{keywords},
    commentstyle=\color{comments},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    showstringspaces=false,
    identifierstyle=\color{green},
    procnamekeys={def,class},
    tabsize=4
}


\begin{document}

\section{Python code}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    language=Python,
    frame=single,   %Remove this option
    numbers=left]
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit import execute, Aer, IBMQ
\end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

Here is what you get after removing the last two options:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Currently `python` environment provided by `pythonhighlight` package is defined as

```tex
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython}}{}
```

which seems buggy: this environment takes one optional argument but never used it. Note the style `mypython` contains `frame=trbl`, which is the cause of frame around code.

I believe the expected definition should be

```tex
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython,#1}}{}
```

A straight solution is to redefine `lst`-environment `python`, but it's actually harder because `listings` provides no way to do env redefinition. Thus the easier option is to define a new `lst`-environment similarly, with a new name:

```tex
\lstnewenvironment{pythonx.y.z}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython,#1}}{} % just for example

\begin{pythonx.y.z}[frame=none]
<python code>
\end{pythonx.y.z}
```

Here is an example showing an attempt to provide `\lstrenewenvironment` then redefine `python` environment:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
%some packages are loaded
\usepackage{pythonhighlight} %package to highlight the Python syntax

\makeatletter
\lst@UserCommand\lstrenewenvironment#1#2#{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\PackageError{Listings}{Environment `#1' undefined}\@eha
     \@gobbletwo}\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname#1@\endcsname\relax
  \expandafter\let\csname end#1\endcsname\relax
  \let\lst@arg\@empty
  \lst@XConvert{#1}\@nil
  \expandafter\lstnewenvironment@\lst@arg{#1}{#2}}

\lstrenewenvironment{python}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython,#1}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Python code}
\begin{python}[frame=none]
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries and configuring account
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit import execute, Aer, IBMQ
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

[image]